# Kohana `index.php` method chaining and minions?

Tags: php, kohana, method-chaining

In the Kohana `index.php` file, there's a clause I have two questions about:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') // Try and load minion
{
class_exists('Minion_Task') OR die('Please enable the Minion module for CLI support.');
set_exception_handler(array('Minion_Exception', 'handler'));

Minion_Task::factory(Minion_CLI::options())->execute();
}
else
{
/**
 * Execute the main request. A source of the URI can be passed, eg:  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].
 * If no source is specified, the URI will be automatically detected.
 */
echo Request::factory(TRUE, array(), FALSE)
    ->execute()
    ->send_headers(TRUE)
    ->body();
}
```

1) what is a `minion`?
2) what does the following mean?

```
->foo()
->bar()
->...etx
```

is that just method chaining?

Comment: 1. A minion is a follower devoted to serve it's master! 2. Those are functions inside an object, probably a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the first part of that code, Kohana is checking to see if your script is running from command line (CLI). If so, it tries to execute a task using Minion.

*Minion is a framework for running tasks via the CLI.*

See: https://github.com/kohana/minion

And: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/minion/

2) And yes that is method chaining that you are seeing in the second part of the code. It could just as easily be rewritten as:

```
$request = Request::factory(TRUE, array(), FALSE);
$response = $request->execute();
$response->send_headers(TRUE);
echo $response->body();
```

Comment: Please note that `Request::execute` returns `Response` object (http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#execute). So, its better to modify your code like: `$response = $request->execute(); $response->send_headers(TRUE); ...`